# Where can I find a multi-threading / concurrency playground?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I am looking for a website or program that has tons of "learn by example" tutorials on multi-threading. Preferably something that I can play with live. The jsfiddle of concurrency. Does such a thing exist?

Thanks!

Comment: more the concepts in general, but C# would be most preferred. thanks

Comment: JSFiddle is really awesome though, thanks I never knew about that.

Comment: Relevant (in Java): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710968/suggest-a-open-source-project-which-heavily-uses-java-concurrency-utilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about large worked examples, but the following two resources (at different levels of expertise and scale) might help.  Both books and the code provided are of excellent quality:

- Java Concurrency in Practice -- Goetz -- [Link to code here](http://jcip.net/listings.html); [Book website here](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/).  This is a more pragmatic book and set of code, focused on issues application programmers want to know.
- The Art of Multiprocessor Programming -- Herlihy --  [Course notes](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs176/); [Book website here](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/ISBN/9780123705914/The-Art-of-Multiprocessor-Programming).  Book contents include Java code.  This is a "for experts" and deeply theoretical book focused (mostly) on low-level concurrent data structures, though with some content on transactional memory.